# Activator with MvvmCross and PCL

Tags: xamarin, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I have a very strange problem. Currently, I am porting a Windows Universal App (Win 8.1 + WinPhone 8.1) with Prism to a CrossPlattform Solution with MvvmCross.
First, a big thanks for all the work with MvvmCross - it is amazing.

My problem is now with the `System.Activator` class. I used [this approach](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html) for my validation in my Universal App and I tried to port it. Now everything is compiling fine but at runtime an nullreference exception gets thrown. I figured out that it is the Acitivator that is null. When I try to access it in the Immediate windows it says:

```
error CS0103: The name 'Activiator' does not exist in the current context
```

The code is executed in every Model and implemented in a base class constructor:

```
protected ModelBase()
{
    foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
    {
        var type = typeof(Property<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType);
        var prop = (IProperty)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        this.Properties.Add(property.Name, prop);
        prop.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(property.Name);
            Validate();
        };
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Activator` is misspelled in the error message, but I assume that this is a typo from when you entered your question? :-)

Comment: MvvmCross itself uses Activator fine - e.g. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c306ba37afd9024f68b7a4f1fedcaf4cf7d01b8d/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Platform/MvxBootstrapRunner.cs#L32 and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c306ba37afd9024f68b7a4f1fedcaf4cf7d01b8d/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Binders/MvxNamedInstanceRegistryFiller.cs#L90 and...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I am feeling a little embarrassed now, because I figured the problem out and it was totally my fault :).

@Anders: You was right, I misspelled the Activator in the Immediate windows and that is why the error was there in the first place - *stupid*.

The second Problem was the ctor of the generated Object.

```
public Property()
{
    this.Errors.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => RaisePropertyChanged("IsValid");
    Errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

Did you find the error? Jap, hooking up to an event on a not created object is a bad idea. Sorry for wasting your time :/ and thanks.